# Leave, or Take a leave

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, politeness

> I think it is a good time for you to leave.

or

considering that we can say the following which is correct:

> I'll take your leave now. Bye.

can I say:

> I think it is a good time for you to take a leave.

Basically I want this person to leave and I don't want to order him to leave. I just want to remind him that it is quite late so he should consider leaving now.

What are the differences between the above sentences. What to say it in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone can either **leave** or **take a leave**, but they are fundamentally different in meaning.

**leave** alone means "go away from a place" (or, figuratively, from a person).

Leave in **take a leave** is short for "leave of absence", aka a break or holiday from work.
So no option in your use case.

Unfortunately, most varieties of

> You may / should / might /... leave now.

although technically correct may come across as somewhat rude for native speakers. But getting the message across without breaking the unwritten rules of hospitality is a dilemma even native speakers face. I recommend looking towards [Miss Manners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_Martin) & co. for advice:

> "Oh my, it's getting late - *I shouldn't keep you any longer!*

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is a good time for your to leave

'leave' here is a **verb**. This means you are asking or suggesting that person to go away from the place for whatsoever reason.

> I'll take your leave now

...is very much Indian I guess. I avoid it and also suggest others the same. This means you are 'asking permission' to leave the place.

> I think it is good time for you to *take **a leave***

no, this means something different. The word 'leave' here serves as a 'noun'. 'Taking a leave' and 'Taking [someone's] leave' don't mean the same. As I said, the latter is Indian and creates an ambiguity (who's 'leave' actually it is!).

When you 'take a leave', officially, you put a notification and there's a process to follow as in companies.

**In your context**, imagine there's a girl and it is quite late. She has to go far to her home and that's the reason, you are *suggesting* her to leave so that she can reach early. In this case,

> I think you should/may leave now. It's getting late.

...is an unambiguous way to convey the message. Again, as I said, if you are talking to a native speaker, 'taking your leave' may sound strange to them.

---

A little trick that might work. If you are confused, ask yourself whether or not the 'leave' you are using is countable? If it is countable, you are talking about 'taking a leave' which means a 'day off' or whatever (that way, the person might have taken ***four leaves*** in a month!). If you cannot count, you are simply using a verb as in `he left the office`.

Comment: In other words, "taking a leave" means taking off from work, with advance notice, for an extended period (longer than a vacation/holiday).

Comment: `If you say, 'You may leave', you are telling that person to quit the place` I don't think "quit" is the best word to use here. That implies resigning from the job.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem oh yes, corrected. Tell me something better if you still feel so! :)

Comment: have edited the question @DJMcMayhem and OP